How do I filter a dashboard based on a date using url parameters?
I want to dynamically filter a dashboard to see only records with a field on a specific date. The documentation doesn't explain how to write a date as a url parameter.
I keep getting the same error "This filter URL is invalid. Please try again".

This is the field i'm trying to filter "Employee Date Unique" which has 2 different dates 14/1/2024 and 14/5/2024.

the filter is setted as the following
"Employee Date Unique equals 14/5/2024"
And is the only filter at the moment

I've tried different formats, like:
view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=14%2F1%2F2024
view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=1%2F14%2F2024
view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=14-1-2024
view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=1-14-2024
view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=%271%2F14%2F2024%27
view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=%2714%2F1%2F2024%27

Tested this out myself on a dashboard.
Mine worked with this:
/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=14%2F01%2F2024
I must also point out that in the filter on the dashboard you are using a date in may (14/5/2024), while in the params you sent you are using January (14/1/2024). If the date isn't in the filter it won't work unfortunately.
So if those are the only 2 dates you want just add 14/1/2024 as another filter value and it should work with url I wrote :)

This helped me to understand what happened. I thougth I could be able to filter with any date I put on the URL. But the date must be firstly setted as a dashboard filter. By  writing the date 14/1/2024 the problem is solved. Thank you!
